# Basic rails form, does not deselect alternative options - can't find solution for rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have excel, video, and multiple choice boolean columns in my Step model.    I am trying to get it so the user has to choose one of the three, and when saved it passes back to the database as true.  Right now my two problems are a)when I select one, it doesn't deselect the others and b) the radio button is on a different line than the text that labels it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <fieldset class="stepCreator">
<%= "Step" %>
<%= f.label :description, "Description" %>
<%= f.text_field :description %>
<div>
<%= f.label :excel, "Excel" %>
<%= f.radio_button(:excel, true, :checked => true) %>
<%= f.label :video, "Video" %>
<%= f.radio_button(:video, true) %>
<%= f.label :multiple_choice, "Multiple Choice" %>
<%= f.radio_button(:multiple_choice, true) %>

</div>

<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>

<%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "btn btn-danger btn-mini remove_fields "%>

 </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have 2 very different problems.

1. All the radio buttons (that you want to select one and automatically deselect the others) must have the same name, and different values, so it should be something like:

   f.radio_button(:media, :excel, :checked => true)

   f.radio_button(:media, :video)
2. For the labels to be at the same line as the checkbox, you just have to change the CSS.

Comment: Okay, I ended up changing my three boolean attributes in one model to one string attribute in the model, and made the radio with each of the values. Do you know what I would do for the css?

Comment: You can use input[type=checkbox] { display: inline } and label { display: inline }

Comment: Also it would be better if you put a class on the checkbox label like <label class="checkboxlabel"> so you can change the css only for checkbox labels like: label.checkboxlabel { display: inline }

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html
try:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:age, "child") %>
<%= label_tag(:age_child, "I am younger than 21") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:age, "adult") %>
<%= label_tag(:age_adult, "I'm over 21") %>
```

radio buttons have to select the same attribute in your model, in this example i selected the age attribute and i can give it 1 of two values, or he is a child or he is an adult

hope it helps

Comment: So there is no way to have a radio button assign true to one of three different attributes in a model, and deselect the other two?